# Using variables in if then

Tags: conditionals

***EDITED FOR MORE CLARITY***

I have a really stupid problem I'm trying to fix... This is (a part of) template code

```
<dl class="tabs contained">
    {if "{products_related_products:total_children}"}
        <dd class="active"><a href="#simpleContained1"><!-- Gerelateerde producten -->{bbr-mls-54}</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if "{products_related_lexicon:total_children}"}
        <dd class="hide-for-small">
        <a href="#simpleContained2"><!-- Gerelateerde lexicon -->{bbr-mls-57}</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if products_additional_remarks_{language_code}}
        <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#simpleContained3"><!-- Bijkomende opmerkingen -->{bbr-mls-53}</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if products_videos_{language_code}}
        <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#simpleContained4"><!-- Video -->Video</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if {exp:playa:total_parents channel="downloads"}!="0"}
        <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#simpleContained5"><!-- Downloads -->Downloads</a></dd>
    {/if}
</dl>
```

This code is shown below a product detail page to show other related content like downloads and videos and so on...

As you can see I'm using a If Then statement to determine if there are any related records for this product and if there are a tab is shown, if nothing is shown.

The problem I'm trying to solve is the set the right tab to class="active".  In the current example this is the case for the first tab in hardcoded way.

In other programming language I would include a variable to every if/then routine and it is executed (because there is content) I would set a variable e.g. ThereIsAnActiveTab to 1
After that I would put a conditional in every

As an example in non-working code this would the code

```
<dl class="tabs contained">
    {if "{products_related_products:total_children}"}
        <dd class="active"><a href="#simpleContained1"><!-- Gerelateerde producten -->{bbr-mls-54}</a></dd>
    {variable:ThereIsAnActiveTab = "1"}
    {/if}

    {if "{products_related_lexicon:total_children}"}
        <dd class="{if variable:ThereIsAnActiveTab=="1"}hide-for-small{if:else}active{/if}">
        <a href="#simpleContained2"><!-- Gerelateerde lexicon -->{bbr-mls-57}</a></dd>
            {variable:ThereIsAnActiveTab = "1"}
    {/if}
```

and so on ... 
But that does not work in EE due the way the template gets parsed.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

rg,

Tim

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? The title mentions using a variable in a conditional, but the question is asking about setting a active class.

Comment: I've added some additional info to make it more clear.. Let me know it helps...

Comment: What type of variable is `variable:ThereIsAnActiveTab`? Global or custom field?

Comment: Is the active tab always the first one?

Comment: What's the condition for a tab to be marked as active?

Comment: variable:ThereIsAnActiveTab is just some pseudo-code...
there are 6 possible tabs on a product detail page.  First I check whether to see there is any info to be shown on the different tabs.  If not the tab is not visible at all.  If there is info, the tab is visible.  But the first visible should be made active (with class="active") all the other visible are not an active tab (with class="hide-for-small")

Comment: Do you need to offer support to IE6? I'm asking because of the first-child selector. The first tab will always be the active one.

By the way, I'm still looking for a EECMS solution.

Comment: no, no IE6 support required luckily.  the solutions proposed by @Siebird works well for this use case.  However still eager to know the server-side EECMS solution too.  Let me know I you find one, I'll do too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code samples, it looks like you have several different custom fields that generate the tabs–so there is really no *clean* way of 'hard-coding' in the first active tab. If your tab structure was within a custom field loop, it would be easy with the `{count}` variable.

If you're using jQuery, you could do this to add the class names:

```
$('.tabs dd:first').addClass('active');
$('.tabs dd').not(':first').addClass('hide-for-small');
```

#### 2nd Option

Using advanced conditionals, but it gets messy quick:

```
<dl class="tabs contained">
    {if "{products_related_products:total_children}"}
        <dd class="active"><a href="#simpleContained1"><!-- Gerelateerde producten -->{bbr-mls-54}</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if "{products_related_lexicon:total_children}"}
        <dd class="{if products_related_products:total_children == 0}active{if:else}hide-for-small{/if}">
        <a href="#simpleContained2"><!-- Gerelateerde lexicon -->{bbr-mls-57}</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if products_additional_remarks_{language_code}}
        <dd class="{if products_related_products:total_children == 0 && products_related_lexicon:total_children == 0}active{if:else}hide-for-small{/if}"><a href="#simpleContained3"><!-- Bijkomende opmerkingen -->{bbr-mls-53}</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if products_videos_{language_code}}
        <dd class="{if products_related_products:total_children == 0 && products_related_lexicon:total_children == 0 && products_additional_remarks_{language_code} == ""}active{if:else}hide-for-small{/if}><a href="#simpleContained4"><!-- Video -->Video</a></dd>
    {/if}

    {if {exp:playa:total_parents channel="downloads"}!="0"}
        <dd class="{if products_related_products:total_children == 0 && products_related_lexicon:total_children == 0 && products_additional_remarks_{language_code} == "" && products_videos_{language_code} == ""}active{if:else}hide-for-small{/if}><a href="#simpleContained5"><!-- Downloads -->Downloads</a></dd>
    {/if}
</dl>
```

Comment: hi siebird, not unfortunately it is not in a field loop. 
Thanks for pointing me the jQuery solution, it works great!

I'm still very interested to know however how I would do this server-sided.  Nevertheless a bit thanks for your suggestion as this issue is solved!!

Comment: Since your tabs are built from several custom fields, you could potentially do this with advanced conditionals that checks if those fields are empty and then apply the correct class. The conditionals would cascaded down and get messy quick. See updated answer.

Comment: thanks!  yes, I explored that path too, but quickly left it as there are other elements on that same page that need similar logic and as you say it becomes quite messy (not to speak the hit on performance)